# Fixing 3rd party API 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, cross-domain

I have an Angular application, currently an HTML file I open but it will soon be converted to a server/accessed through localhost. I use $http to access a 3rd party API (I have no control over its responses; most of the API calls work, but some don't and throw the error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&api_key=RJEnADgGbCjfJYi0z8vuVnelYXn2Smud2Dfi2u2F&q=susage. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

The API calls that throw that error are the searches that return 0 results (in the example, the database returns no results for "susage"). In the Network tab, the response can't be loaded and no response headers are listed; for other working API calls, under Response Headers, the necessary "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" is present.

The API definitely forms a response and tries to send it back, but fails for whatever reason. Visiting the posted url shows that response.

Why do only the empty searches throw the error when API understands and has a response for both calls, and how do I fix it? I would prefer that my frontend communicates with the API directly, as opposed to communicating with my backend which in turn communicates with the API.

For comparison, a search with results (spelling 'sausage' correctly) vs a search without results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGjPB.jpg

The $http code:

```
return $http.get('http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json', {
            params: {
                api_key: usdaKey,
                q: query
            }
        })
```

Comment: So, you're saying that a response with results doesn't throw that message but one with no results does?

Comment: Correct. I'll edit in the metadata for an example working request/response.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any way of knowing without understanding the API.  The error could be coming from some internal call based on receiving an invalid query.  I would just handle the 404 in the client code, treating it as a "no results found".  If that's not sufficient then I'd submit a question to the owner of the API to see if the current behavior is expected.

Comment: Do I do that with http interceptors or is there an easier way?

Comment: An interceptor might be overkill.  If your just making the API call from a single controller or service then you can handle the error in the return of the promise that is the $http.get

Comment: I was trying to suppress the error from the console entirely, but now I understand that is impossible (and is intended by the browser). The problem I have now is that the error object the promise is rejected with has a status code of -1, even though the logged error specifies status 404. This is problematic as it's the code for other actual errors, such as the internet being disconnected.

Comment: Can you update your question with your http call including the promise handling?  That'll help me help you.

Comment: Never mind ... I see where your issue is.  Check my answer for the resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to expose the "-1" status (timeout) to the UI, I changed the service method to simply return the promise, like this:

```
var search = function(query) {
  return $http.get('http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json', {
    params: {
      api_key: usdaKey,
      q: query
    }
  });
};
```

Then you can handle the error in your controller, like this:

```
$scope.search = function(query) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.err = null;
  foodInfo.search(query).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.items = response.data.list.item;
  }, function(e) {
    console.log('Error status: ' + e.status);
    if (e.status === -1) {
      $scope.err = 'No data found';
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Switching to that causes $http to think it is a local file; I'm not sure if that's because I am currently just opening an HTML file instead of using localhost. This was the error: Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///home/tahsis/myIO/api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&api_key=RJEnADgGbCjfJYi0z8vuVnelYXn2Smud2Dfi2u2F&q=a'.

I'll also edit in my original $http call.

Comment: Ok, sorry I forgot that your page is a standalone file.  I believe it will still work as long as you include JQuery in your file.

Comment: I've had jQuery (1.12.3) included  :/

Comment: Hmm, frankly I'm not all that familiar with running from the file system. Is there a reason you don't just serve up the page from localhost?

Comment: I haven't gotten around to it yet. I've used the MEAN stack before but wanted to code a project from scratch without generating any files and express is the part I know least about. I'll repost the question when I switch if the problem persists.

Comment: If that's the case, why don't you build the page on plunker?  That way you won't waste time with issues related to the file system approach and when you're ready to move it to localhost you won't have to change your code.

Comment: I moved the code to a plunkr and the problem that the promise error has a status of -1 remains (generic error, e.g. also used for disconnected internet). I included jQuery and tried to remove the 'http://' from the $http call, but that still resulted in the browser thinking the path is relative to the application's server. http://plnkr.co/edit/fNpuRCDqu0AuyCAjun93?p=preview.

Comment: I forked your plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6V59LrwcrwnBrFozdN2N?p=preview and made some changes to handle the "-1" status.  Apparently in Angular 1.4.6 they introduced "-1" as a status to indicate a timeout.  I'll also change my answer to reflect the plunker.